# Dagger can not provide my dependencies

Tags: java, android, dagger-2

I'm having a problem with Dagger 2.
I want a general NetworkModule where I can share my retrofit, etc.. and then later on I want subcomponents so that per flow I have different Retrofit Interfaces for example login, ...

My setup right now is:

```
@Module
public class NetworkModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    @Named("Default")
    Retrofit provideRetrofit() {
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .baseUrl("myUrl")
                .build();

        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

I also have a ApplicationModule ( I don't know if this is the correct way to have a ApplicationModule ).

```
@Module
public class ApplicationModule {
    private Application application;

    public ApplicationModule(Application application) {
        this.application = application;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Application providesApplication() {
        return this.application;
    }
}
```

And last but not least my Component that binds the two together:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {ApplicationModule.class, NetworkModule.class})
public interface NetworkComponent {
    Retrofit provideRetrofit();
    void inject(MainActivity activity);
}
```

Now I don't see the problem but when I do:

```
((MyApplication) getApplication()).getNetworkComponent().inject(this);
```

Where this is created as:

```
DaggerNetworkComponent.builder().applicationModule(new ApplicationModule(this)).build();
```

I can't compile and I get the error:

retrofit2.Retrofit cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or from an @Provides- or @Produces-annotated method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `@Named("Default")` to your `Retrofit provideRetrofit();` in `NetworkComponent`

Comment: So put your all error log and code there you inject Retrofit @user1007522

Comment: It works. When trying some things out I suddenly removed the Named in the activity so I added that again and then the @Named like you suggested. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the following classes for the usage of dagger 2 and retrofit :

**Injector.java**

```
public class Injector {

// Singleton instance
private static Injector instance;

// components
private AppComponent appComponent;

// Private constructor to make it singleton
private Injector() {
}

/**
 * Get the singleton Injector instance
 *
 * @return Injector
 */
private static Injector instance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new Injector();
    }

    return  instance;
}

/**
 * Creates application component which used of injection later.
 *
 * @param application
 */
public static void createApplicationComponent(Application application) {
    if (instance().appComponent == null) {
        instance().appComponent = DaggerAppComponent.builder()
                .appModule(new AppModule(application))
                .build();
    }
}

/**
 * Returns the component for injection.
 *
 * @return
 */
public static AppComponent component() {
    return instance().appComponent;
}

}
```

**AppComponent.java**

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {
    AppModule.class,
    ApiModule.class,
})
public interface AppComponent {
// Other utility classes for injection
}
```

**ApiModule.java** which similar to your network module class

```
@Module
public class ApiModule {

@Provides
@Singleton
public Retrofit provideApi(
        OkHttpClient client,
        Converter.Factory converterFactory,
        CallAdapter.Factory callAdapterFactory) {
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(Config.API_BASE_URL)
            .client(client)
            .addConverterFactory(converterFactory)
            .addCallAdapterFactory(callAdapterFactory)
            .build();

    return retrofit;
}
}
```

**AppModule.java**

```
@Module
public class AppModule {

private Application application;

public AppModule(Application application) {
    this.application = application;
}

@Provides
@Singleton
public Application provideApplication() {
    return application;
}

@Provides
@Singleton
public Context provideContext() {
    return application;
}

}
```

later in your activity class you can use `Injector.component().inject(this);` to inject dagger 2 dependencies

For more clarification you can refer [this](https://github.com/iamdeowanshi/android-mvp) github repo